# Is there a websocket api for rinkeby?

Tags: etherscan, rinkeby

Is there an api for etherscan and rinkeby websocket? I've checked the link below https://etherscan.io/apis#websocket but see no way of accessing websockets in rinkeby. Is there a way to test the web socket etherscan api on rinkeby to see my test transactions go through?

Comment: Do you know about infura? You can connect to any public network using infura

Answer (score 1):

It appears not, because https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/apis#websocket doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Infura provides one for Rinkeby over [here](https://web3j.readthedocs.io/en/latest/infura.html).

> https://rinkeby.infura.io/(your-token-address)

Comment: This doesn't address the question, which was about Etherscan's websocket API. "Is there a way to test the web socket etherscan api on rinkeby...?" Infura supports the web3 websocket subscription interface, but that's unrelated to the Etherscan API.

Comment: @smarx My suggestion was for a comparable option from infura. It looks like I missed the actual question at the end.